# Submitting to arXiv with Springer style

Tags: arxiv, draft, sv-classes

I am submitting my accepted manuscript to [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/). To me, the whole process is confusing. You can create a dirty PDF in Windows and they accept it, but when your manuscript is created with LaTeX, you should provide the source code with a [not-so-obvious format and settings](https://arxiv.org/help/submit_tex).

I am submitting the source anyway, but as it is a Springer style manuscript, the draft version of `svjour3` class (`\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}`) includes some undesired text about journal information, etc. So, what should I do? Submit in `article` class, or submit the draft version of journal paper as it is generated by `svjour3` class?

This is what I get:

[image: Undesired header]

This is a smaple published paper (from `svjour` manual):

[image: Right header]

I think it would be ok if I could just remove the header.

This is a minimal working example, please help me remove the header:

```
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}

\date{Published 2016}


\begin{document}
\title{Sample of the standard layout for journal articles}

\author{First Author \and Second Author \and Third Author}

\maketitle

\abstract{Abstract An abstract is required for regular articles.}

\keywords{Keywords First keyword, Second keyword, More}

\section{Introduction}
It is common to name the first section of an article Introduction.

\end{document}
```

Comment: In the paper 1404.2797 we also used an elsevier style with a partially filled header. No problem for arXiv. Of course you could adapt your code to `article`, or `revtex`, or whatever: it's your time `;-)`

Comment: @campa Thanks for the suggestion. I checked `svjour3.cls` and it seems that the header is hardcoded in what is provided to us in TeX distributions.

Comment: May you give me `latex o overleaf` template? I want to write an article like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I think there is no problem in publishing the paper on the arXiv with the box (I've done it and I've seen it a lot of times), the simplest way would be to redefine

```
\def\makeheadbox{\relax}
```

in the preamble. This eliminates the box but leaves the thick horizontal line below it. If you want to eliminate that too, then you must redefine `\@maketitle` (lines 546-629 in `svjour3.cls`). To be completely honest I don't think it's worth the time. You could of course adapt your code to `article` or `revtex`, but depending on how the paper is written this can become time consuming.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is better not to remove the contents of `\makeheadbox`.

According to [Springer's self-archiving policy](https://www.springer.com/gp/open-access/authors-rights/self-archiving-policy/2124) **you need to acknowledge the publisher** before uploading your manuscript somewhere (personal website or arXiv). They treat pre-prints and author's accepted manuscripts (AAMs) differently. If it is AAM, in addition to the acknowledgement, there is also an Embargo Period (currently 12 months) - which means, you can put the accepted version on arXive only after 12 months, but this does not apply to your own self-maintained website. (Read the policy, it is short and clear in contrast to IEEE policy). The acknowledgement they require for AAMs goes like this:

> This is a post-peer-review, pre-copyedit version of an article published in [insert journal title]. The final authenticated version is available online at: http://dx.doi.org/[insert DOI]

Therefore I put this acknowledgement in the aforementioned `\makeheadbox`.
Unfortunately, this thing usually does not fit into the header of their svjour3.cls template, so I slightly changed the wording. You can use the following code based on campa's great answer and svjour3.cls definition of the `\makeheadbox`:

```
\def\makeheadbox{{%
\hbox to0pt{\vbox{\baselineskip=10dd\hrule\hbox
to\hsize{\vrule\kern3pt\vbox{\kern3pt
\hbox{\bfseries [Insert journal name here]}
\hbox{This is a post-peer-review, pre-copyedit version of this article.}
\hbox{The final authenticated version is available online at: \href{[Insert doi here]}{[Insert doi here]}.}
\kern3pt}\hfil\kern3pt\vrule}\hrule}%
\hss}}}
```

The result looks like this:
[image: Acknowledgement to Springer in \makeheadbox]

Good thing about this method is that you use it in your .tex file (e.g. just above the `\begin{document}`) and do not need alter the class files, **which is strongly discouraged**.

Comment: I think this should be the correct answer. Springer allows immediate publication of pre-review pre-prints but embargoes post-review copies. I'd change the wording from `This is a post-peer-review, pre-copyedit version of this article.` to `This is a pre-peer review, pre-print version of this article.` to make this clear and not get into copyright beef with Springer.